# Max Height And Max Width Validtation Before Jquery Upload Preview

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

Ok so I'm trying to do a max height max width validation before jquery upload preview so that if the image is larger than the max height or max width to alert user and ask them to choose a smaller photo. How would i be able to do that part of code?

html code:

```
<img id="uploadPreview" style="display:none;"/>

<!-- image uploading form -->
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="uploadImage" type="file" accept="image/jpeg" name="image" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload">

<!-- hidden inputs -->
<input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
<input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
<input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
<input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
</form>
```

jquery code:

```
function setInfo(i, e) {
    $('#x').val(e.x1);
    $('#y').val(e.y1);
    $('#w').val(e.width);
    $('#h').val(e.height);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var p = $("#uploadPreview");

    // prepare instant preview
    $("#uploadImage").change(function(){
        // fadeOut or hide preview
        p.fadeOut();

        // prepare HTML5 FileReader
        var oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            p.attr('src', oFREvent.target.result).fadeIn();
        };
    });

    // implement imgAreaSelect plug in (http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/)
    $('img#uploadPreview').imgAreaSelect({
        // set crop ratio (optional)
        aspectRatio: '1:1',
        onSelectEnd: setInfo
    });
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? Once you have put the image element into the DOM and it has loaded, where’s the problem, you just check it’s width and height …

Comment: @CBroe Well I Tried Putting In maxHeight: 1100, maxWidth: 1100 but that didnt work and thats all i tried because i dont know much about jquery nor javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just replace your script.js by

```
function setInfo(i, e) {
    $('#x').val(e.x1);
    $('#y').val(e.y1);
    $('#w').val(e.width);
    $('#h').val(e.height);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    var p = $("#uploadPreview");
    // prepare instant preview
    $("#uploadImage").change(function () {
        var that=this;
        // fadeOut or hide preview
        p.fadeOut();
        // prepare HTML5 FileReader
        var oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);
        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = oFREvent.target.result;
            image.onload = function () {
                if ((this.width > 400) && (this.height)) {
                    that.value="";
                    alert("choose another file");
                }
                else {
                    p.attr('src', oFREvent.target.result).fadeIn();
                }
                // access image size here & do further implementation
            };
        };
    });
    // implement imgAreaSelect plug in (http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/)
    $('img#uploadPreview').imgAreaSelect({
        // set crop ratio (optional)
        aspectRatio: '1:1',
        onSelectEnd: setInfo,
        maxHeight: 100,
        maxWidth: 100
    });
});
```

It will help..